# Trying to find a solution to a problem related to the recursive sequence $S_{n}^{k}(a)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, induction, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

I'm working on a problem related to a recursive sequence, and I'm having some trouble. The sequence $S_{n}^{k}(a)$ is defined as follows:

$$S_{n}^{k}(a) = 
\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{a} & \text{if } n = 1, \quad a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \, a \neq 1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sqrt{d_i} & \text{if } n > 1, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}
\end{cases}$$

where $d_i$ represents the $i$-th digit of the previous term $S_{n-1}^{k}(a)$, and $k$ represents the number of digits of $S_{n-1}^{k}(a)$ from which we extract and sum the square roots.

The problem goes as follows:

How many different combinations of $a$, $n$ and $k$ exist such that the following equality is satisfied: $$S_{n}^{k}(a) = S_{n+1}^{k}(b)$$
where $b = a^2$

Can anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to approach proving this base case? Any insights or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

*(I am not a native English speaker, so I might be using the incorrect terms)*